# py2app gui error

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, py2app

I have a very simple gui app: http://pastebin.com/aVVTBJPd

This is written in Python and wxPython. It runs fine on my Mac.

I tried running py2app. Here are my exact steps:

```
$ py2applet --make-setup gui.py
$ #returns "Wrote setup.py" (this appears to have been successful)
$ python setup.py py2app #this prints out A LOT of stuff in the terminal, also 
$ #seems to be working ok
```

Then, I go into my dist directory, and double click on gui.app, immediately receive gui error.

[image]

Here's what comes out in the console:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461983/evt-tickcount-not-found-with-python2-6-on-osx-10-6-3) help ?

Comment: Try setting `'argv_emulation': False` in your `setup.py`. See also [Optimizing for OSX in wxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X).

Comment: this is old, but it looks like it is looking for an image in your shared library and not finding it... my guess is that no icons were included in your so. i'm on windows, not mac, so can't help with how to actually fix it, but maybe that will point in the right direction.